# Can't find element by id - selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Despite use `id` I can't locate input element. I have tried `CssSelector`, `Xpath`, `Id` already. Why can't handle this element this way?

I have tried:

```
By id = By.Id("First name:input");
By xpath = By.Xpath("//*[@id=\\"First name:input\\"]");
By selector = By.CssSelector("#First\\ name\\:input");
```

I use `explict wait` to wait for input element.

Input Element:

```html
<div class="controlPaddingWrapper">
<label id="First name:">First name:</label> 
<input ng-attr-id="{{ c.Prompt+ 'input' }}" next-focus="" focus-if="true" class="k-textbox ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern flow-required ng-touched" pattern=".+$" ng-model="c.Value" ng-class="{'flow-required': isRequired(c)}" required="" style="width: 100%;" ng-change="onChange(c)" id="First name:input" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting any exception with these locators?

Answer (score 0):

[HTML The id Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp)

Try just: `By id = By.Id("First name");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
By xpath = By.Xpath("//input[@id='First name:input']");
By selector = By.CssSelector("input[id='First name:input']");
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to invoke `Click()`/`SendKeys()` on the desired element, as the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element you need to indice *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input.k-textbox.ng-pristine.ng-empty.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required.ng-valid-pattern.flow-required.ng-touched[id*='First']"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@class='k-textbox ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern flow-required ng-touched' and @id=\"First name:input\"]"))).Click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Better change the  ID's without space `<label
   id="First_name">`
2. If you like to search by Id then try this: `By.id("First_name")`
3. If you like to by XPath: `By.Xpath("//*[@id='First_name']")` or
   `By.Xpath("//label[@id='First_name']")` OR `By.Xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'First name:')]")`
   For Xpath reference you can find in here https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Sorry never been used By.CssSelector

```html
<div class="controlPaddingWrapper">
<label id="First name:">First name:</label> 
<input ng-attr-id="{{ c.Prompt+ 'input' }}" next-focus="" focus-if="true" class="k-textbox ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern flow-required ng-touched" pattern=".+$" ng-model="c.Value" ng-class="{'flow-required': isRequired(c)}" required="" style="width: 100%;" ng-change="onChange(c)" id="First name:input" type="text">
</div>
```